# Change button colour and function after click

Tags: php, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have a green **join** button which enables users to join a group. Users can then see the groups they have joined from their logged in dashboard. Data is stores in a `groups` table in the database.

I want the button to turn red once it's clicked and read **Unjoin**.

I know that each link has five different states: `link`, `hover`, `active`, `focus` and `visited`, and whilst `visited` would be the normal option, I need to ensure a logged in user will always see the red **Unjoin** button, even if they clear their cache or something.

Would I need to make the button communicate with the database to verify a user has joined a group, or would this be done with javascript or something else?

**EDIT**

Thank you @TanvirAhmed for the below code. It partially worked, logged out users see GREEN and logged in see RED. But, logged in users ALWAYS see red, whereas they should only see RED if they've previously joined the group.

```
@if(Auth::user() == '')

<form method="post" action="{{ route('groups.join') }}">
@csrf
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Join Group</button>
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="{{ $group->id }}" />
</form>

@else

<form action="{{ route('groups.destroy', $group->id)}}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>

@endif
```

I'm just left with the problem of redirection when the red delete button is clicked.

I don't want to redirect the user after clicking the delete button, they should remain on the current page `{{ route('groups.show',$group->id)}}`.

However, I need the button action to delete (`destroy`) the user user from group, so I understand I need `{{ route('groups.destroy', $group->id)}}`.

How, then, do I perform both the destroy route AND leave users on the current page?

GroupController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Group;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// All Groups pages require login except 'show'
class GroupsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'show']);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $groups = Group::where('created_by_user_id', auth()->id())->get();

        return view('groups/index', compact('groups'));
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function joined()
    {
        //@todo change query to show groups joined
        // $groups = Group::where('created_by_user_id', auth()->id())->get();
        // $groups = Group::with('joinedUsers')

        $groups = auth()->user()->groupsJoined()->get();

        return view('groups/joined', compact('groups'));
    }

    /**
     * Store the group that a user has joined in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function join(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        $group = Group::find($request->get('group_id'));
        $group->joinedUsers()->attach(auth()->id());

        return redirect('groups/joined')->with('success', 'You joined the group!!');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('groups.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)

    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_title' => 'required',
            'group_description' => 'required',
            'group_date' => 'required',
            'group_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $group = new Group([
            'group_title' => $request->get('group_title'),
            'group_description' => $request->get('group_description'),
            'group_date' => $request->get('group_date'),
            'group_time' => $request->get('group_time'),
        ]);
        $group->save();
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group saved!!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        // $group = Group::find($id);
        $group = Group::with('createdByUser')->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('groups.show', compact('group'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        return view('groups.edit', compact('group'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_title' => 'required',
            'group_description' => 'required',
            'group_date' => 'required',
            'group_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $group = Group::find($id);
        $group->group_title =  $request->get('group_title');
        $group->group_description = $request->get('group_description');
        $group->group_date = $request->get('group_date');
        $group->group_time = $request->get('group_time');
        $group->save();
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        $group->delete();
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group deleted!');
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide some code or progreess of your question

Comment: will do, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blade you can use like this..

```
@if(Auth::user()=='')
///your join/green button
@else
//your red /unjoin button
@endif
```

Try this and let me know what is happening there 
to stay on the show page replace your controller code from the below code

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        $group->delete();
        return back();
    }
```

and also it is good practice to confirm before delete like below you can use

```
<form action="{{ route('groups.destroy', $group->id)}}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I've added my last issue of how to redirect in my post, please take a look if you can. Thank you.

Comment: give me the links

Comment: I spoke too soon, the button is now always RED, regardless of if a user has joined a group or not! Which links? I have included all the links I am using in the original post (just updated it).

Comment: I feel the first line is where my problem is ```@if(Auth::user() == ' ')``` I need to put something between the quotes to make sure it knows who the user is?

Comment: Auth::user() meansthe user who logged in your system

Comment: Ok, so that should work. I wonder why the button is RED all the time? I'm just trying more things to try and resolve. Will update here if any success.

Comment: Ah, Ok your code does work, logged out users see GREEN and logged in see RED. But, logged in users ALWAYS see red, even when they have not joined the group.

Comment: Thanks @TanvirAhmed, you helped a lot and I feel I am almost there! I have a second stage to this question but will create a fresh post so it's clearer for people to see where I am.

Comment: Ok will check now. I literally just posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171757/button-behavior-to-be-different-for-joined-unjoined-users so you may have actually answered it .. checking now.

Comment: Thanks for the confirm text, good point. Also, before I add your code to stay on show page, I really need to resolve the issue of 'not' showing a RED button to users who have joined the group (they should see 'green'). See details in link above.