# Button behavior to be different for joined / unjoined users

Tags: php, laravel

My app allows users to join groups if they click a green 'Join' button. Once clicked, they should then see a RED 'unjoin' button.

Here's my button:

```
@if(Auth::user() == '')

<form method="post" action="{{ route('groups.join') }}">
@csrf
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Join Group</button>
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="{{ $group->id }}" />
</form>

@else

<form action="{{ route('groups.destroy', $group->id)}}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Unjoin</button>
</form>

@endif
```

Logged out users see GREEN and logged in see RED, which is correct, but logged in users ALWAYS see red, even if they have joined the group. Hmmm?

I think the issue is the first `if` statement because it's only checking for logged in users, when actually it's more imposrant to check for users who have
joined the group. So, I tried this:

`@if(Auth::user() == 'joinedUsers')`

but it still only shows a RED button, how do I change query to show RED button only if a group has been joined by user?

GroupController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Group;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// All Groups pages require login except 'show'
class GroupsController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'show']);
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
$groups = Group::where('created_by_user_id', auth()->id())->get();

return view('groups/index', compact('groups'));
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function joined()
{
//@todo change query to show groups joined
// $groups = Group::where('created_by_user_id', auth()->id())->get();
// $groups = Group::with('joinedUsers')

$groups = auth()->user()->groupsJoined()->get();

return view('groups/joined', compact('groups'));
}

/**
 * Store the group that a user has joined in storage.
 *
 * @param\Illuminate\Http\Request$request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function join(Request $request)
{
$request->validate([
'group_id' => 'required',
]);

$group = Group::find($request->get('group_id'));
$group->joinedUsers()->attach(auth()->id());

return redirect('groups/joined')->with('success', 'You joined the group!!');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
return view('groups.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param\Illuminate\Http\Request$request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)

{
$request->validate([
'group_title' => 'required',
'group_description' => 'required',
'group_date' => 'required',
'group_time' => 'required',
]);

$group = new Group([
'group_title' => $request->get('group_title'),
'group_description' => $request->get('group_description'),
'group_date' => $request->get('group_date'),
'group_time' => $request->get('group_time'),
]);
$group->save();
return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group saved!!');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @paramint$id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
// $group = Group::find($id);
$group = Group::with('createdByUser')->where('id', $id)->first();
return view('groups.show', compact('group'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @paramint$id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
$group = Group::find($id);
return view('groups.edit', compact('group'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param\Illuminate\Http\Request$request
 * @paramint$id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
$request->validate([
'group_title' => 'required',
'group_description' => 'required',
'group_date' => 'required',
'group_time' => 'required',
]);

$group = Group::find($id);
$group->group_title =$request->get('group_title');
$group->group_description = $request->get('group_description');
$group->group_date = $request->get('group_date');
$group->group_time = $request->get('group_time');
$group->save();
return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group updated!');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @paramint$id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
$group = Group::find($id);
$group->delete();
return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group deleted!');
}
}
```

User.php

```
     */
    public function groupsJoined()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'group_joined_user', 'user_id', 'group_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: put a column in Group model named "user_name". Then in a view take dropdown where you can select user to participate in a group. Then perform a join query on both table. And then ou can check your condition properly.If you dont understand then let me know

Comment: I have a model called User.php (see above).  The database table which holds the groups that users join is called ```groups_joined_user```. I am not sure what you meant by 'perform join query'?

Comment: `Auth::user()` is an object of the auth'd user. `{{ dd(Auth::user()) }}` in your blade view to see its properties (email, name ...)

Comment: dd(User::with('groupsJoined'))->get();....................can yo give me the outputs of this?? I want to check the relations data of this.

Comment: You might need to be very specific as I've not been coding long. What are the outputs you need? I have several pages and I'm sure one of them is what you need; Controllers = ```GroupsController.php``` ```ProfilesController.php``` 
Models = ```Group.php``` ```JoinedGroup.php```
Pages = ```groups/index.blade.php``` ```groups/show.blade.php``` ```groups/joined.blade.php``` 
Route = ```routes.web.php```

Comment: RE: dd(User::with('groupsJoined'))->get();. Do I put this in the header of the show.blade.php?

Comment: No, in controllers inside of any function

Comment: I tried it a few controller, inside the function and refreshed the webpage. Nothing happened, the pages just display as normal?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple groups, so how do you determine which group to join with your form? Maybe the form could be like this?

```
@foreach($groups as $group) {
    @if(auth()->user()->hasJoinedGroup($group))
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('groups.join', $group->id) }}">
          @csrf
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Join Group</button>
        </form>
    @else
        <form action="{{ route('groups.destroy', $group->id)}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Leave group</button>
        </form>
    @endif
    </form>
@endforeach
```

And in the Controller:

```
The join function: 
/**
 * Store the group that a user has joined in storage.
 *
 * @param\Illuminate\Http\Request$request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function join(Request $request, $groupId)
{

$group = Group::find($groupId);
$group->joinedUsers()->attach(auth()->id());

return redirect('groups/joined')->with('success', 'You joined the group!!');
}
```

Similarly adjust other functions like unjoin & destroy. In User Model,

```
public function hasJoinedGroup($group){
    foreach($user->joinedGroups()->all() as $joinedGroup){
        if($joinedGroup->id == $group->id){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In show() function in GroupController,

```
public function show(){
    $groups = Group::all();
    return view('groups.show',compact('groups'))'
}
```

Comment: I determine which group a user will join because they will first be logged in and which ever group they are looking at, that group has a unique id. Thank you for your feedback, I will look through your suggestions now.

Comment: I used your code exactly and I get ```Undefined variable: groups (View: C:\laragon\www\version2\resources\views\groups\show.blade.php)```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, will try this after dinner - need some brain energy! I wish it were something simple like: ```@if(Group::is('JoinedbyUser')) button=red @else button=green @endif``` !!

Comment: It didn't like what you asked me to put in the User Model, the first line had error on the word ```class ```

Comment: Little typo there, its actually function.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for my reply, I just re-read and it sounded very aggressive. I think I meant to say "I did what you asked me", and not "I didn't like..".  I was typing very fast but 100% appreciate all your efforts to help me.

Comment: No, I still get "Undefined variable: group" on the ```show.blade.php``` page?